# Capturing negative matches in Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, backreference

I'm trying to do a non-greedy negative match, and I need to capture it as well. I'm using these flags in Python, re.DOTALL | re.LOCALE | re.MULTILINE, to do multi-line cleanup of some text-file 'databases' in which each field begins on a new line with a backslash. Each record begins with an \lx field.

```
\lx foo
\ps n
\nt note 1
\ps v
\nt note
\ge happy
\nt note 2
\ge lonely
\nt note 3
\ge lonely
\dt 19/Dec/2011

\lx bar
...
```

I'm trying to ensure that each \ge field has a \ps field somewhere above it within its record, one for one. Currently, one \ps is often followed by several \ge and thus needs to be copied down, as with the two lonely \ge above.

Here's most of the needed logic: after any \ps field, but before encountering another \ps or \lx, find a \ge, then find another \ge. Capture everything so that the \ps field can be copied down to just before the second \ge.

And here's my non-functional attempt. Replace this:

```
^(\\ps\b.*?\n)((?!^\\(ps|lx)*?)^(\\ge.*?\n)((?!^\\ps)*?)^(\\ge.*?\n)
```

with this:

```
\1\2\3\4\1\5
```

I'm getting a memory error even on a tiny file (34 lines long). Of course, even if this worked, I would have to run it multiple times, since it's only trying to handle a second \ge, and not a third or fourth one. So any ideas in that regard would interest me as well.

**UPDATE:** Alan Moore's solution worked great, although there were cases that required a little tweaking. Sadly, I had to turn off DOTALL since otherwise I couldn't prevent the first .* including subsequent \ps fields--even with the non-greedy .*? form. But I was delighted to learn about the (?s) modifier just now at regular-expressions dot info. This allowed me to turn off DOTALL in general but still use it in other regexes that it **is** essential for.

Here is the suggested regex, condensed down to the one-line format I need:

```
^(?P<PS_BLOCK>(?P<PS_LINE>\\ps.*\n)(?:(?!\\(?:ps|lx|ge)).*\n)*\\ge.*\n)(?P<GE_BLOCK>(?:(?!\\(?:ps|lx|ge)).*\n)*\\ge.*\n)
```

That worked, but when I modified the example above, it inserted the \ps above "note 2". It also was treating \lxs and \ge2 the same as \lx and \ge (needed a few \b). So, I went with a slightly tweaked version:

```
^(?P<PS_BLOCK>(?P<PS_LINE>\\ps\b.*\n)(?:(?!\\(?:ps|lx|ge)\b).*\n)*\\ge\b.*\n)(?P<AFTER_GE1>(?:(?!\\(?:ps|lx|ge)\b).*\n)*)(?P<GE2_LINE>\\ge\b.*\n)
```

and this replacement string:

```
\g<PS_BLOCK>\g<AFTER_GE1>\g<PS_LINE>\g<GE2_LINE>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible with a regular language (the *“somewhere above”* kind of does that). You should simply write a parser or something for it and create the correct output on the fly.

Comment: I think that regex is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: I agree that it's pushing the limits, but see my reply to thebjorn's answer for my reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the memory error because you used the `DOTALL` flag.  If your data is really formatted the way you showed it, you don't need that flag anyway; the default behavior is exactly what you want.  You don't need the non-greedy modifier (`?`), either.

Try this regex:

```
prog = re.compile(r"""
    ^
    (?P<PS_BLOCK>
      (?P<PS_LINE>\\ps.*\n)
      (?:                   # Zero or more lines that
        (?!\\(?:ps|lx|ge))  # don't start with
        .*\n                # '\ps', '\lx', or '\ge'...
      )*
      \\ge.*\n              # ...followed by a '\ge' line.
    )
    (?P<GE_BLOCK>
      (?:                   # Again, zero or more lines
        (?!\\(?:ps|lx|ge))  # that don't start with
        .*\n                # '\ps', '\lx', or '\ge'...
      )*
      \\ge.*\n              # ...followed by a '\ge' line.
    )
    """, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
```

The replacement string would be:

```
r'\g<PS_BLOCK>\g<PS_LINE>\g<GE_BLOCK>'
```

You'll still have to do multiple passes.  If Python supported [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html), that wouldn't be necessary, but you can use [`subn`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.subn) and check the `number_of_subs_made` return value.

Comment: Thanks! With just a small tweak, that worked great for me. I've added the specifics in an update to my question above. I did like your verbose documented regex, BTW, but unfortunately had to condense it into one line due to my text file's format.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you're having problems with regexen and tell yourself "I would have to run it multiple times,.." it's a clear sign that you need to write a parser :-)

The language seems to be pretty regular, so a a parser should be easy to write, perhaps starting with something as easy as:

```
def parse_line(line):
    kind, value = line.split(' ', 1)  # split on the first space
    kind = kind[1:]                   # remove the \
    parsed_value = globals().get('parse_' + kind, lambda x:x)(value)
    return (kind, parsed_value)

def parse_dt(value):
    val = ... # create datetime.date() from "19/Dec/2011"
    return val
```

It's maybe a little too cute to use `globals()` to write a state machine, but it saves a ton of boilerplate code... :-)

Convert your input into a list of tuples:

```
records = [parse_line(line) for line in open("myfile.dta")]
```

Figuring out if there is always a `("ps", ..)` tuple before a `("ge", ..)` tuple should then be pretty easy -- e.g. by first noting where all the `lx` tuples are...

Comment: et al: Looks slick. The reason I'd like to use a regex here (even though code is easier) is that I'm storing an ordered set of regexes in a text file. So, I provide a script the user can run and even customize, with descriptions and a simple way of en/disabling each regex, so they can customize even without knowing regex. (And in plain text no characters need to be escaped.) The other regexes I've been making are much more reasonable. Several use .* multiline; hence the DOTALL.